# Passing string parameter to a function using sapply

Tags: r, data-science

I have a dataset which holds data for cars sold in each continent.I am trying to find the cars which is sold maximum in each continent.I have columns which specify the number of cars sold in each continent(EurSales,AsiaSales,NASales,SASales..).

I have written the below function and trying to find out the max sales but am facing some errors.

```
 #cars is the dataset
 maxSales<-function(columnName){
 return(Cars$Name[which.max(Cars[,columnName])])
 }

 colNames <- c("EurSales","AsiaSales","NASales","SASales");
 maxCarSales <- sapply(colNames,maxSales)
```

I get a error stating 
 **Error in `[.data.frame`(cars, , columnName) : 
  undefined columns selected**

But if try to hard code the columnName,the function works perfectly fine.It also works fine if i directly call the function.Am I doing anymistake while passing the string as a param?

Comment: You forgot a `,` i.e. `Cars[which.max(Cars[, columnName]),]`

Comment: @akrun,there was a typo.I had to find out Cars$Name.Tried using your solution,didnt work :(

Comment: Figured out the issue.One of columns names i was passing was wrong. :(

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution works perfectly.The typo was in the column names being passed.